# Maximal set on hypersphere that does not contain pairs of orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let R be a region on a hypersphere. Each point A of the hypersphere 
is associated with a vector pointing to A and with origin at
the centre of the hypersphere. So let me identify each point with a
vector. I have the constraint that every pair of vectors in R is 
not orthogonal. What is the maximal region R satisfying this
constraint? I guess that this region, up to rotations, is given
by two opposite hypercones with 90 degrees angular aperture. This
is intuitive, but the proof is not so simple to me.

Comment: When you say that you want "the" maximal region, it seems to imply that such a region is unique.  I don't think that there is a unique such R...

Comment: Could you define "region"?  Presumably a region is not just an arbitrary set, but rather must have some connectivity properties...?

Comment: I guess that the region is unique up to rotations, but one could just ask what is the maximal area.

Concerning the properties of the region, I require only that it is measurable and has an area defined. The region is not necessarily connected.

Comment: Keeping the dimension at 3 for discussion, there is not only the spherical cap of angular width just shy of 90 degrees, but also the nonnegative orthant minus three points.  And these are connected examples.  There are nonconnected examples that take up even more of the sphere's surface area.  I leave it to those more facile with higher dimensions to generalize these examples. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.18

Comment: For 1-circles the optimal solution is not unique: instead of taking two opposite open arcs of length π/2, you can take six equally-spaced open arcs of length π/6, for instance.

Comment: To Gerhard. It is true that the orthant does not contain orthogonal vectors, however it is not maximal.

To David, it is assumed that the dimension of the surface is > 1.

Comment: The orthant may not be maximal, although I think two orthants may be.  However, I know of no maximal connected subset of the sphere that contains this orthant and has your property as well.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.18

Comment: Just consider two opposite caps, as suggested in the question. They contain two orthants. Furthermore they do not contain pairs of orthogonal vectors.

Comment: Alberto, I disagree.  Neither a cap nor an orthant contains the other, is my belief.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.18

Comment: Gerhard, you are right. However it is true that the area given by two orthants is smaller than the two-cap area. In the first case is 1/4 of the total area, in the second case is $1−1/\sqrt2\simeq0.29$, if I am not wrong.

Comment: I think this is known as the "double cap conjecture", and in particular would imply better estiamtes in the "Borsuk problem". The person to ask is probably Gil Kalai. See e.g. http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/how-large-can-a-spherical-set-without-two-orthogonal-vectors-be/

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the information!